# Why is Camera turning different than Player with same code in different scripts?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, mixamo

I want to integrate a running character in my game, I downloaded the animation via Mixamo. The player is running and if I attach the camera directly to the Player it's shaking the camera and the game is not playable. 
So I made a different script for the camera. In there, the camera follows always the player but turns, like the player, via

```
    float h = PlayerMovement.horizontalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

    transform.Rotate(0, h * Time.deltaTime * 60, 0);
```

(for the camera) and

```
    float h = horizontalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

    transform.Rotate(0, h * Time.deltaTime * 60, 0);
```

for the player. But after a view seconds I'm running in a completely different way then I look. Why is that and how can I solve this?

I tried different animations - nothing worked.

**Update:** If there is no rigidbody and no collider attached to it it works fine. But I need them.

Comment: I am assuming horizontalSpeed is a static public float?

Comment: @Eddge Yes, sorry, forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0):

remove this:

float h = horizontalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");

```
transform.Rotate(0, h * Time.deltaTime * 60, 0);
```

and drag the camera onto the play. as a child of the player the camera will follow and turn with the play.

if the camera is already a child of player, this would explain why your getting a messed up turn, because your changeing the players angle, by x, which changes the camera angle by x, and then your changeing the camera angle by x again, making them not line up.

Comment: I believe he does not have the camera as a child of the player because,  *`if I attach the camera directly to the Player it's shaking the camera and the game is not playable.`*

Comment: ahhh i guess i glanced right past that. he should remove the rotation script from the camera and try it as a child of the player.

Comment: @PrinceOfRavens Re-read his question.  He already tried that as well.

Comment: Like @Draco18s mentioned, this is not working, because every part of my player is shaking and the camera would as well. At the moment camera and Player are not attached!